# for не выполняется

Tags: python

Я пишу программу, чтобы складывать (как минимум) дроби. Пишу в программе Sublime Text 4. Код:

```
a = input("Format: 1/2 Input: ")
b = input("Input: ")
a.partition('/')
b.partition('/')
numberOn1 = int(a[0])
numberUnder1 = int(a[2])
numberOn2 = int(b[0])
numberUnder2 = int(b[2])
nullList = [0,1,2,3,4]
num = 0
operator = input("Operator: ")
if operator == '+':
    for n in nullList:
        fraction1 = ''
        fraction2 = ''
        num += 1
        if num % numberUnder1 == 0:
            if num % numberUnder2 == 0:
                oneMult = num / numberUnder1
                twoMult = num / numberUnder2
                numberOn1 = numberOn1 * oneMult
                numberOn2 = numberOn2 * twoMult
                fraction1 = numberOn1,'/',num
                fraction2 = numberOn2,'/',num
                print(fraction1,fraction2)
                break
        else:
            continue

print("End")
input()
```

Так в чём суть? Программа просто не производит действий из for. Я перенёс print из остального кода в for и узнал, что for вообще не выполняется. Ну и что делать?

Comment: Перенес куда именно?

Comment: Проверил в [онлайн-компиляторе](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/). Всё прекрасно работает и цикл выполняется. Не совсем понятно, правда, что именно вы кодите, но то уже такое.

Comment: проблема в `nullList`, там слишком мало значений, например: если ввести `1/2`, `3/4` и `+`, тогда все работает, но если ввести `1/5`, `3/8` и тот же плюс, то программа ничего не выведет

Comment: @zolars если программа ничего не выводит, то это совсем не означает, что она не работает.

Comment: @Эникейщик я имею в виду, что программа не работает так, как она должна

Comment: @zolars Почему это вдруг? Если программа ничего не выводит, то это совсем не значит, что она не работает, как она должна. Во-первых, вы не знаете, как она должна работать. А во-вторых, вы и сами можете придумать кучу примеров, когда программа ничего не выводит, но работает так, как нужно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Я знаю как она должна работать, в вопросе это указано, я проверил код у себя на компьютере, на нескольких тестах и понял, при каких он работает, как задумывал автор, а при каких нет, и в соответствии с этим написал свой комментарий

Comment: @zolars В вопросе ничего про то, как должна работать программа и что она вообще должна делать, не сказано. Ну и мы отвлеклись. Моя основная мысль - один только факт, что программа ничего не выводит, не означает, что она не работает или работает не так, как нужно.

Comment: @Эникейщик первое же предложение вопроса: `Я пишу программу, чтобы складывать (как минимум) дроби`, и после этого вы говорите, что в вопросе ничего про цель программы не сказано? да и просто из кода и так ясно, что он делает

Comment: @zolars Ну пусть написано. А из кода ВСЕГДА ясно, что он делает. Но далеко не всегда понятно, что он ДОЛЖЕН делать. Что делает функция ``def t(x): return x+3`` ясно. А вот что она должна делать - нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик, согласен, теперь я понял что вы хотели сказать, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите складывать дроби и при этом сокращать их, то это можно сделать гораздо проще, тут не нужен ни `for`, ни `nullList`, вот мой пример как это можно сделать, он не идеален и не работает умножение с делением, но складывание и вычитание работает прекрасно:

```py
from math import gcd

numberOn1, numberUnder1 = map(int, input("Format: 1/2 Input: ").split("/"))
numberOn2, numberUnder2 = map(int, input("Input: ").split("/"))

operator = input("Operator: ")

simplifier = gcd(numberUnder1, numberUnder2)
commonUnder = numberUnder1 * numberUnder2 // simplifier
commonOn = eval(str(numberOn1 * numberUnder2 // simplifier) + operator + str(numberOn2 * numberUnder1 // simplifier))
simplifier = gcd(commonOn, commonUnder)

print(commonOn // simplifier, "/", commonUnder // simplifier, sep="")
input("End\n")
```

а ваш код не работал, как раз таки из-за `nullList`, так как в нем было слишком мало значений